# Get value from the previous loop using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I would need to keep the value from the loop where authorId = 1 and then print it out as another value in the next loop (authorId = 3). I mean that I need to keep authorSurname.value (id = 1) and print it in the loop (authorId = 3) as the secondAuthor.value because in the loop (authorId = 3) the string authorSurname takes another value. Can you tell me how can I fix it?

```
  if(authorId === 0) { 

div.innerHTML = firstAuthorSurname.value + year.value + page.value + pageOtherValue;
}

else if (authorId === 1) {
       div.innerHTML = firstAuthorSurname.value + " i " + authorSurname.value + " (" + year.value + "); 
       var secondAuthorSurname = authorSurname.value;
}

else if (authorId === 2) {
    return secondAuthorSurname; 
    div.innerHTML = firstAuthorSurname.value + ", " + secondAuthorSurname.value + " and " + authorSurname.value + " (" + year.value + ") " + firstAuthorSurname.value + ", " + secondAuthorSurname.value + " and " + authorSurname.value + ", " + year.value + ")" + firstAuthorSurname.value + ", " + secondAuthorSurname.value + " and " + authorSurname.value + ", " + year.value + ") showed that... ";
}
```

Comment: your example code does not contain a loop

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not contain a loop but if you would like to save a value to use outside of a for loop declare the variable outside the loop and then you will have access to it outside the loop.

```
text = "";
cars = ["honda", "chevy"];
for (i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) { 
  text += cars[i]; 
}
console.log(text);
>>hondachevy
```

If you are trying to save a value to be used in a different condition in the if statement inside a for loop you can follow the same pattern

```
text = "";

for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) { 
  if(i === 0){
   text += "to be used when i is 1";
 }
 else if(i === 1){
   console.log(text);
   text += " hello";
 }
}
console.log(text);
```

output

```
>>to be used when i is 1
>>to be used when i is 1  hello
```

Also why don't you use a switch statement instead of a long if else. See the link below for how to do switch statements in javascript.

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp